# Using /c as an argument in CygWin bash script, without translation

Tags: bash, parameters, cygwin

I'm trying to run `regedit /c reg.txt` from within a CygWin `bash` script to grab the registry contents after which I'll process them with the remainder of the script (yes, I know Powershell is one option but I'd rather stick with the tools I know).

However, when doing this, the `regedit` program pops up a dialog box complaining about trying to read `c:\` and I *think* this is because CygWin magically converts the `/c` into the actual drive `c:\`, similar to the way that `cat /h/xyzzy/plugh.txt` will show me the file `h:\xyzzy\plugh.txt`. The dialog box is as follows, you can see the errant parameter underlined:

[image]

Is there a way I can stop this translation from happening so that `regedit` gets the parameters as intended? I've thought of running the regedit separately in a `.cmd` file but it's a real pain having to maintain two separate files to do a single job <sup>(a)</sup>.

I've also tried running it with `cmd /c` but that appears to suffer from a similar problem - it just opens up a new command interpreter and waits for input, presumably because the `/c` is being translated to `c:\`. While `cmd /k dir` will list the directory and remain, `cmd /c dir` does nothing in the `cmd.exe` instance.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It *will* work if I use `cmd /k otherscript.cmd` and then explicitly exit at the end of that script. However, as I said, it's a bit kludgy and I'm pretty certain it would break the second I mount a network share on the `k:` drive and CygWin starts translating `/k` into `k:\` :-)

Comment: Does `regedit '/c' reg.txt` work?

Comment: No go, @EtanReisner, good idea but still gets same error showing "c:\". Also tried upper-case C just in case, still no joy.

Comment: Does `echo /c '/c'`  show `/c /c` or `c: c:`? Does (long shot) `command regedit /c reg.txt` work?

Comment: The echo shows `/c /c` which seems funny. The command doesn't work either.

Comment: It means cygwin is being smart and doing the translation only for Windows commands (I think). Which is why I was hoping `command` might "confuse" it. But no such luck apparently. Does `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/c regedit /c reg.txt` work? What about `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/c; regedit /c reg.txt; unset -v MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL`?

Comment: Don't apologize to me. I don't think I can be of much more help at this point though. Sorry.

Comment: @EtanReisner: WTH? After all that, I wrote a Windows program to echo the arguments and a page I found when looking for the MSYS2... stuff that you mentioned is right. Using `//c` will translate to `/c`. But I couldn't figure out why it was still complaining in that case about the third argument. It's because I'm stupidly using `/c` when it should be `/e` - I must have gotten confused between regedit and cmd.

Comment: In any case, since your comment led me to the answer, feel free to put in a real answer and I'll adjust it with the necessary detail and accept it. No reason why you shouldn't get the rep for it :-) If you don't want to, I'll do it myself in a couple of days. If you want to reference the page, it's at http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion.

Comment: Hah! I almost suggested `//c` at least twice but stopped myself because that wouldn't really make sense. Glad you found it. You can write it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this MSYS page](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) (upon which MinGW is based, upon which your Git for Windows is based), MSYS will automagically convert POSIX paths to Windows paths for executables not linked to the MSYS DLL.

This includes translating `/c` into `c:\`, which is what you're seeing. This explains why both `regedit /c reg.txt` and `cmd /c dir` aren't working since the former is attempting to use `c:\` as an *input* to `regedit` (prompting the warning you see) and the latter is simply starting `cmd` without executing the arguments.

The method used to prevent translation is to double up the slash, with something like:

```
regedit //c reg.txt
cmd //c dir
```

MSYS will remove the leading `/` and refuse to translate the remainder of the argument, so you'll end up with the `/c` argument.

You'll *still* have issues with the first command above since the correct command-line switch to export the registry is `/e` rather than `/c`. Change that (and use `//e` from within MinGW, of course) and it will do what you want.